# relation between limits of $f$, $f'$ and $f''$

Tags: limits

Let $f\in C^2[0,\infty)$ and $g$ a continuous and bounded function over $[0,\infty)$ such that $f''(x)=g(x)f(x)$. Suppose that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$. Prove that $f'(x)\to\ell\in\mathbb{R}$?

What I tried is that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f''(x)=0$ since $g$ is bounded and $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to \infty$. Also, I have proved that $f'$ is a bounded function. I used the fact that $f$ is continuous and converges to $0$, therefore, it is bounded over $[0,\infty)$. That implies that $f''$ is also bounded. Using Taylor's theorem, I could prove that $f'(x)$ is bounded. 
Is that enough to have that $f'(x)\to \ell \in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: if $\int_0^\infty g(x)dx<\infty$ then that is correct. if not, it's a bit difficult to imagine

Comment: I think $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f'(x) = 0$. Here is the reference: https://mathpost.asu.edu/~hliu/Things2Explain/Barbalat's%20lemma.pdf

Comment: I read it. The problem is that $f'$ is not uniformly continuous.